# ASP.NET SwaggerGen mark readonly resource properties as required

Tags: asp.net, .net, typescript, swagger, openapi

I have a Resource (DTO) that can only be read:

```
public class QuestionVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public QuestionComplexity Complexity { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryIdNameVM> Categories { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }
    public int Answers { get; set; }
}
```

OpenApi considers each of these properties optional (non-required) which causes a bit of trouble when using OpenApi Generators (In TS all my QuestionVM's properties come optional)
How do I override this behavior a proper way?
I want my non-nullable types to be required by default

One of the possible solutions is to mark each property with [Required] attribute, but it looks a bit not obvious to me. (why would readonly model need to have required attributes?)
Also, C# required doesn't make any effect

I have tried this:

```
// Explicitly mark non-nullable properties as required.

public class RequiredSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema.Type == "object")
        {
            foreach (var openApiSchema in schema.Properties)
            {
                if (openApiSchema.Value.Nullable == false)
                {
                    schema.Required.Add(openApiSchema.Key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't care about nullability - it marks any ref type as nullable (ignoring default value, required modifier)